# Disable sort/filter for existing grid column

Tags: layout, magento-1, event-observer, grid

Is it possible to disable `filterable/sortable` for an existing grid column via `observer` or `layout update`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using _prepareColumns() method,

```
$this->addColumn('Your column', array(
  'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Object'),
  'index'     => 'item',
  'filter'    => false,
  'sortable'  => false
));
```

Comment: Via abserver or layout update for an existing column?